# Find /home/user in python as root user

Tags: python

When I want to get user directory as normal user in Python, then i can simply do  this:

```
os.path.expanduser('~')
--> /home/user
```

But, when I run this command as the root user, then it shows this result.

*Running as root*:

```
os.path.expanduser('~')

--> root
```

Is there any way to get **/home/user** directory as root user in python3?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to do `os.path.expanduser('~user')`, e.g. `os.path.expanduser('~fpm')`

Comment: If you mean when you are pivoted into the `root` account from another account by way of `sudo`, and want to find the home directory of the invoking user, try `os.path.expanduser('~' + os.environ['SUDO_USER'])`. If you mean something similar but without necessarily assuming they used `sudo`, it's probably trickier.

Comment: If you are running the script as `root`, then the expected answer should be `/root` as that is the home folder of the `root` user. However if you are running executing the script by means of `sudo`, then you can find the relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70415125/399435

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
username = os.getenv("USER") 
if(username != 'root'):
    print(os.path.expanduser('~'+username))
```

Comment: What happens if the user is root?