# Get home directory path in Python on Linux as root

Tags: python, path

I have a script where I need the path string of the current user. I am using `os.path.expanduser("~")`. My problem is that if I execute the script as `root` the path is `/root`, where I wanted to have something like `/home/user-name`. How can I achieve this in Python3?

This snippet

```py
from os.path import expanduser
print(expanduser("~"))
```

when called as root `sudo python3 test.py` returns:

```
/root
```

Comment: How did you expect the program to know that you mean `user-name` by `~` and not `another-user`?

Answer (score 2):

**Update** after post edit.

Use `os.environ` to get the `SUDO_USER` variable or as fallback `USERNAME`.

Script `test.py`:

```
import os

username = os.environ.get('SUDO_USER', os.environ.get('USERNAME'))
print(os.path.expanduser(f'~{username}'))
```

Execution:

```sh
$ python test.py
/home/louis

$ sudo python test.py
/home/louis
```

From `man sudo`:

> SUDO_USER        Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.

---

**Old answer** before your edit.

Use `os.path.expanduser` :)

```
>>> os.path.expanduser('~louis')
/home/louis
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?